# Replace does not work inside a function

Tags: python, function

I noticed the following strange behaviour when I try to use `replace` in a function. Let's say we have the following function:

```
def string_replace(string, arg):
    string.replace(arg, "")
    return string
```

This function is supposed to get rid of the `arg` in the `string` argument, but it doesn't seem to work. For example:

`string_replace('There.', '.')
< There.`

But if I type:
`"There.".replace(".", "")` everything goes smoothly.

Any logical explanation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python strings are immutable so you are not modifying it in place. Any of the following will work:

```
def string_replace(string, arg):
    string = string.replace(arg, "")
    return string

def string_replace(string, arg):
    return string.replace(arg, "")
```

Comment: Yep, thanks. The other post was quite helpful as well.